# Error initializing enunciate - generate step error

Tags: maven, enunciate

I have configured my REST/Spring/Jersey project to generate documentation for APIs using enunciate.

The relevant changes in my pom.xml are

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enunciate-spring-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.28</version>
        <configuration>
            <generateDir>${project.build.directory}/enunciate-generate</generateDir>
          <configFile>enunciate.xml</configFile>
          <exports>
            <jaxws.client.library.binaries>client.jar</jaxws.client.library.binaries>
          </exports>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>assemble</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
.....
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-enunciate-spring-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.28</version>
    </dependency>
```

My enunciate.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<enunciate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://enunciate.codehaus.org/schemas/enunciate-1.28.xsd">
<api-classes>
<include pattern="com.xxx.rest.*"/>
</api-classes>
<modules>
<docs docsDir="api" title="REST WebServices API"/>
<spring-app>
<war mergeWebXML="war/WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
<springImport file="war/WEB-INF/applicationContext-jdbc.xml"/>
</spring-app>
</modules>
</enunciate>
```

When I run my maven project I get the following error initializing enunciate. As you can see the error is not very helpful. Any hints what could be wrong in my configuration.

--- maven-enunciate-spring-plugin:1.28:assemble (default) @ xxx ---
initializing enunciate.
[csharp] C# compilation is disabled, but the source code will still be generated.

### invoking enunciate:generate step...

### BUILD FAILURE

### Total time: 3.324s

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-spring-plugin:1.28:assemble (default) on project xxx: Problem assembling the enunciate app. String index out of range: 0 -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: what happens when you run the command with `-e`?

Comment: @tieTYT Here's my -e output: Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.ImportedClassesClasspathHandler.handleResource(ImportedClassesClasspathHandler.java:55)
 at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.scanClasspath(Enunciate.java:457)
 at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.doGenerate(Enunciate.java:350)

Comment: java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658) rg.codehaus.enunciate.main.ImportedClassesClasspathHandler.handleResource(ImportedClassesClasspathHandler.java:55org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.scanClasspath(Enunciate.java:462)atg.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.doGenerate(Enunciate.java:355)atrg.codehaus.enunciate.ConfigMojo$MavenSpecificEnunciate.doGenerate(ConfigMojo.java:670)atrg.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate$Stepper.step(Enunciate.java:1799)atrg.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate$Stepper.stepTo(Enunciate.java:1831)atrg.codehaus.enunciate.AssembleMojo.execute(AssembleMojo.java:71).

Comment: After some sleuthing figured out that I had some swagger dependency in my pom.xml that was causing enunciate to throw the above error. I removed the swagger dependency and now I am able to go past the above error. I however get this error now. Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-spring-plugin:1.28:assemble (default) on project dcat-rest: Problem assembling the enunciate app. The invocation of APT has failed. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-771 for a case where this has been seen. There is no explanation for this error. -> [Help 1].....Investigating

Answer (score 0):

That `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` was reported and fixed [here](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/issues/42).

The "invocation of API has failed" is almost always caused by some compile failure. Maybe when you messed with your dependencies to get around the first problem, you introduced a compile failure in your code base?